# Не могу получить имя и фамилию пользователя vk по id

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api

```
    final VKRequest request =   VKApi.users().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.FIELDS, "first_name, last_name")); `

    request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
            VKApiUserFull user = ((VKList<VKApiUserFull>)response.parsedModel).getById(192644453);
            Log.d("User name", user.first_name + " " + user.last_name);
        }
    });
```

Возращает null

```
04-11 23:10:52.430 28181-28181/com.example.belzik.messagefromvk E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: com.example.belzik.messagefromvk, PID: 28181
                                                                                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String com.vk.sdk.api.model.VKApiUser.first_name' on a null object reference
                                                                                      at com.example.belzik.messagefromvk.MainActivity$1$2.onComplete(MainActivity.java:90)
```

Но если вместо `users` использовать `friends.get()`, то все отлично получается

```
    final VKRequest request =   VKApi.friends().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.FIELDS, "first_name"));`

    request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
            VKApiUserFull user = ((VKList<VKApiUserFull>)response.parsedModel).getById(192644453);
            Log.d("User name", user.first_name );
        }
    });
```

Результат:

```
04-11 23:47:56.569 18330-18330/com.example.belzik.messagefromvk D/User name: Александр
```

Comment: апи возвращает массив юзеров, даже если он был один.. так что не хватает обращения по индексу 0...... что-то типа `user[0].first_name`

Comment: мне кажется, что вам в самом запроссе нужно указать ограничение по id. Или вы думаете, что API  вам вернет все 100 млн. пользователей, и они влезут в вашу память?

Comment: я использую `user.getById()` поэтому должен получить определенного юзера из листа

Comment: Ну если верить доке, то без id он выполняет запрос по id текущего пользователя. Наверное, у текущего пользователя ид не `192644453`. В callback задавать id нужного пользователя уже поздно, запрос отработал и данные пришли.

Comment: `VKApiUser user = ((VKList<VKApiUser>)response.parsedModel).get(0);` сработает?

Comment: да, подскажите тогда, что нужно сделать, чтобы получать данные других пользователей

Comment: где тогда нужно задавать id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тестируем сдесь
https://new.vk.com/dev/users.get
Вызов в java

```
            VKParameters parameters = new VKParameters();
            parameters.put("user_ids", /*ваш id пользователя*/;
            VKRequest request = new VKRequest("users.get", parameters);
            request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
                    super.onComplete(response);
                    //код обработки объекта
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(VKError error) {
                    super.onError(error);
                }
            });
```